# StackOverflow daily themes

Tags: discussion, questions

No, I'm not suggesting a Bing-like background, so let's get that out of the way.

What I am asking about is whether anyone else has noticed that questions on StackOverflow sometimes seem to come in grouped by topic.  For example, today I answered several questions for which the answer was a `xx.TryParse[Exact]()` function all from different people and completely independent of each other.  Other days I'll find three or four linq questions, again all completely independent.

Has anyone else noticed this, is it my imagination, or is it just a statistical quirk, like the odds of two people in a small group having the same birthday being surprisingly high?

Comment: To ​the​ dump​!

Comment: When the Lone Ranger mines SO data, he goes *to the dump, to the dump, to the dump, dump, dump!*

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it happens because there is an assignment in a class about that topic that day, so a bunch of students in the class flock to SO for help.

...or maybe once *one* question is posted, other people say to themselves "Hey I'm going to test out that solution" or "I was wondering about something similar", and then they come up with similar problems/issues to raise as additional question.

Comment: No, at the least the questions I'm thinking about.  They're typically not related to each other at all.  They just share a common theme.

Comment: What kind of a terrible student would do that? Do they not understand the point of studentship?

Comment: @Welbog: many don't.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's like when you buy a new car. Suddenly it seem like that car model is all over the place. So if you "notice" a question for whatever reason, suddenly it will be popping up all over the place.

Comment: In the same way, people might be reading popular programming blogs that talk about some feature of language X. I wonder if there is a correlation?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be contagious questions. Someone sees a question about LINQ, and they go "Oh yeah, I wanted to ask XX about LINQ too!" Like yawns, and smiles.

Answer (score 0):

No, I've noticed it too, on more than one occasion.  I have no proof to back it up, but questions definitely seem to come in waves.